# How to add values?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

New to Assembly language, reading a book here. I'm trying to do an simple basic exercise. Using appropriate registers, I have to add 100, 200, 300, 400, 500. Don't know where to start with this program. This is the outline of the program, now I need to add the registers. This is what I have, from what I understand from the book. Don't know how to keep adding.

```
(AddSub.asm)
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.code   

main PROC

    mov eax, 100
    add eax, 200

exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: *now I need to add the registers*. Not really. `mov eax, 100` puts `100` into `eax`. Then `add eax, 200` adds `200` to `eax`, making `eax` contain 300. With assembly language, what you see is what you get.

Comment: downvoting because this seems too trivial.  The community is more forgiving of trivial questions about asm than most languages, but this is like asking "how would I add another  `x += 300;` to my existing C program"?  Don't all procedural languages work by stringing statements one after the other?  I'm not trying to be rude, because obviously you have to start somewhere while learning.  I'm just saying that you should keep reading your asm book, or maybe look for another one if the answer isn't clear yet, because this doesn't seem like a good SO question.  Come back later when you know more :)

Comment: Although I agree with @PeterCordes , I'll remain neutral about the vote. Had there been no code between `main PROC` and `exit` I would have readily downvoted and voted to close. Yes, it is a trivial task, with a trivial answer, and unfortunately the solution is itself trivial. There is an opportunity to also present some ideas that may help (like printing the number to the screen using Irvine's library etc). This would have been a duplicate of other questions had it been about adding 2 numbers.

Answer (score 4):

If you have experience with higher level languages like *C*, then these lines:

```
mov eax, 100
add eax, 200
```

Would do something akin to:

```
int eax;
eax = 100;       /* mov 100 to EAX */
eax = eax + 200; /* add 200 to EAX */
```

If you want to add other numbers you keep adding to *EAX* like:

```
add eax, 300
add eax, 400
```

You can use other registers besides *EAX* (like *EBX*,*ECX*,*EDX*,*ESI*,*EDI*). You can also add these registers together. For example

```
mov eax, 100
mov ebx, 200
mov ecx, 300
add eax, ebx
add eax, ecx
```

This would be akin to:

```
int eax = 100;
int ebx = 200;
int ecx = 300;

eax = eax + ebx; /* add EBX to EAX */
eax = eax + ecx; /* add ECX to EAX */
```

Which would result in a value of 600 in *EAX*

Using *Irvine32* library you can print the contents of *EAX* as a signed integer by calling the `WriteInt` function like so:

```
call WriteInt
```

Comment: It's more akin to `eax += 200`, `eax += ebx`, and `eax += ecx`.

Comment: I was unsure if the OP had any knowledge of C so I expanded it out so it would be clear. I didn't want to explain `+=` if they hadn't seen it before. It was meant to be more pseudo codish than C-ish.

Comment: Sure, but I wanted to avoid the `a = b + c` construction because x86 does not have 3-operand add.

Answer (score 3):

Just add more `add` instructions:

```
add eax, 300
add eax, 400
add eax, 500
```

You also have to print out the result somehow, before your `exit` line.

Comment: He has `exit` there which is presumably a macro coming from the `Irvine32.inc`. So that's taken care of :)

Comment: @Jester Ah, thanks! The indentation threw me off, sorry. (That's what being a Schemer does to you.)

Comment: But it's nevertheless a valid point and might help somebody else :)

Comment: @Jester , yes `exit` is defined by one of the files _Irvine32.inc_  includes. It is simply defined as `exit EQU <INVOKE ExitProcess,0>  ; exit program`

Comment: With Irvine32  library you can print out the contents of _EAX_ by doing a `call WriteInt` for signed numbers or `call WriteDec` for unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should keep adding `add` the numbers to the eax register right after the `mov` instruction. From the little i know this is what the eax is for.

```
section .text


global __start
__start:
mov eax, 100
add  eax, 200
add eax, 300
add eax, 400
add eax, 500

; you can print it out here

mov eax, 1
Int 0x80
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: That seems like NASM for Linux. But the question is about MASM for Windows.

Comment: @rkhb Oops sorry i am also new to assembly and i am learning on linux thats why. But i guess the procedure is the same.

Comment: Among other things on Windows there is no `int 0x80` for system calls.